# How can a read only property(element.classList) can be modified or assigned to some other value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e) {
    const key= document.querySelector(`div[data-key='${e.keyCode}']`);
    console.log(key.className);
    console.log(key.classList);
    key.classList=['ajay','dish'];
}
```

```html
<div data-key="65" class="key ajay">
   <kbd>A</kbd>
</div>
```

[image]

Above is a screenshot of chrome devtools with values modified.

I read on  [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) that `element.classList` is read only property but can be modified by `add()` etc.

I assigned it to some other array and that is working too.

In other cases, whenever I tried to modify/assign read only property, it always gave `typeError`.

Comment: some properties are "magic" in the DOM/BOM; `window.name`. `window.location`, `elm.classList`, etc. if you want to do this yourself, look into `setters`, or more recently and granular, `Proxy`s

Comment: *classList* is a method of a host object. It's not described in great detail in either specification referenced by MDN: [*WHATWG HTML Living Standard*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#dom-classlist) and [*W3C DOM*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-classlist). Generally, browsers try to be accommodating where technologies aren't clearly defined or have a solid *de facto* standard. So in this case, assigning an object to *classList* seems to set the *className* property to the default *toString* of that object. But do not rely on that.

Comment: Oh, *classList* implements the DOM [*DOMTokenList* interface](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-domtokenlist).

Answer (score 5):

Very good question.

I did not originally know the exact answer to your question, but I'm not surprised as much by the behaviour. The spec defines the minimum that all compliant useragents (browsers) must implement. It also defines all the features that developers can expect and rely on when targeting compliant useragents (browsers). It's up to the browsers to add additional non-standard features.

This means that all browsers have to implement a `get` property called `classList`. Developers should only expect a `get` property to be available in browsers. Browsers might think it's convenient for developers to have a `set` function implemented too. It's fairly common for browsers to do this kind of thing. Sometimes this kind of features gets added to a newer version of the standard, sometimes it never makes it because the standard committee disagrees with the purity of the feature.

Sometimes non-standard features get deprecated and even removed, which although takes years - is a good reason for developers to *not* rely on non standard features when other standard features can achieve the same goal (for example, the property `className` can be used to override the `classList`).

## But how is it done technically after all?

Chrome implements this in a very clever way (might be originally WebKit). It applies an attribute `PutForwards` to the definition of `classList`.

This allows the property to be defined as `readonly`, but when assigned a value, one of the properties of the object gets assigned instead, not the entire object. In this case, the child property name is `value`.

So, the code `document.body.classList = '123';`
is the same as `document.body.classList.value = '123';`

You can confirm the object was not replaced by running the following in Chrome console

```
const body = document.body;
const oldClassList = body.classList;
const oldValue = body.classList.value;
body.classList = "new-class";
const newClassList = body.classList;
const newValue = body.classList.value;
console.log(
  "classList changed:", oldClassList !== newClassList, // false
  "value changed:", oldValue !== newValue // true
);
```

The definition of `classList` in Chromium source code

```
[Affects=Nothing, SameObject, PerWorldBindings, PutForwards=value] readonly attribute DOMTokenList classList;
```

can be found at:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/4141778eb03a31a20d9e109f74faf2f756b4a8c4/third_party/blink/renderer/core/dom/element.idl#L37

Note how this is different from the definition in the spec

```
[SameObject] readonly attribute DOMTokenList classList;`
```

which can be found at https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#element

And the test in the source code that explains the relation between the attribute and the ability to override the readonly property in its comment

```
// Even though classList is readonly, PutForwards=value means that its value is forwarded.
```

can be found at:
https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/f18e79d901f56154f80eea1e2218544285e62623/third_party/WebKit/LayoutTests/fast/dom/HTMLElement/resources/class-list.js#L13

Comment: Side note: The DOM spec browser-engine implementors actually implement from is https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/ (and the corresponding relevant link is https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#element). That’s the only authoritative, actively-maintained spec for the DOM. https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/ is a very out-of-date copy of a much older version. And in general it’s not prudent to read or reference specs in https://www.w3.org/TR/, because they are almost always out of date. The up-to-date versions of W3C specs are nowadays instead in https://w3c.github.io/ space — e.g., https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/

Comment: Also note that PutForwards is a standard feature of the WebIDL interface-definition language that all browser implementations rely on. The relevant behavior describe here is standard cross-browser required behavior defined in the WebIDL spec at https://heycam.github.io/webidl/#PutForwards

Comment: As of today the W3 standard actually contains the `PutForwards` attribute in the spec, i.e. it's no longer just a Chrome thing: it's in the spec.